# How do I change the bot skins on my CS:Source Dedicated Server?

Tags: counter-strike-source

How do I change the bot skins on my CS:Source Dedicated Server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `botprofile.db` in your `cstrike` directory. In it, you will have a section with a form like:

```
Elite+Rifle Clive
    Skin = 1
    VoicePitch = 95
End
```

If you change the number in the `Skin`line, the bot will have a different skin.

I presume the numbers are IDs, so you will need to discover which skin is which number by trial and error as I cannot find a source for the defaults online.

Comment: Thank you very much, if you do find out please let me know =) haha